# Is there a way to get the magic mouse or MacBook Pro trackpad to work with the iphone simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, trackpad, magic-mouse

It seems like the perfect opportunity for the trackpad or the magic mouse to work with the iphone simulator but it doesnt?!

Does anyone know how to get it working to allow me to touch and pinch?

Comment: "Why" is kind of an off-topic question here (only Apple can answer that). "Is there a way to get it to work" may be better suited. I'd change the title, if I were you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it looks similar, it is different: The trackpad gives a pinch event, but the iPhone/iPad needs concrete taps with absolute coordinates (which the trackpad does not offer). As far as I know it is not possible to track individual fingers on the trackpad.